# Gantt Chart usig pgfgantt with year divided into months

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, pgfgantt

I have created the following Gantt chart using `pgfgantt` package.

[image]

I want to increase the width of Month columns and would appreciate if you suggest me any other efficient approach to achieve the same Gantt chart. Thanks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\ganttset{group/.append style={orange},
milestone/.append style={red},
progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{document}

%    \begin{figure}
%    \centering
     \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=0.7cm,
     vgrid, hgrid,
     title height=1,
%     title/.style={fill=none},
     title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar/.style={fill=blue},
     bar height=0.7,
%   progress label text={},
     group right shift=0,
     group top shift=0.7,
     group height=.3,
     group peaks width={0.2},
     inline]{1}{11}
    %labels

    \gantttitle[]{2017}{11} \\                 % title 
    \gantttitle{Jan}{1}                      % title 3
    \gantttitle{Feb}{1}
    \gantttitle{Mar}{1}
    \gantttitle{Apr}{1}
    \gantttitle{May}{1}
    \gantttitle{Jun}{1}
    \gantttitle{Jul}{1}
    \gantttitle{Aug}{1}
    \gantttitle{Sep}{1}
    \gantttitle{Oct}{1}
    \gantttitle{Nov}{1}\\

    % Setting group if any

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5}\\ 

    \ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4}\\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 2}{2}{10} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=2,inline=false]{Test 1}{6}{9} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 2}{7} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=5,inline=false]{Test 2}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 3}{10} \\       

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 3}{3}{8} \\ 

    \ganttbar[progress=90,inline=false]{Task A}{3}{5} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=50,inline=false, bar progress label node/.append style={below left= 10pt and 7pt}]{Task B}{3}{4} \\ \\
    \ganttbar[progress=30,inline=false]{Task C}{5}{6}\\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=70,inline=false]{Task D}{8}{10} \\ 

\end{ganttchart}
%    \caption{Gantt diagram for 2013--2014 Project}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `x unit` which by default is 0.5 cm. See page 7 in `pgfgantt` documentation.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\ganttset{group/.append style={orange},
milestone/.append style={red},
progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{document}

%    \begin{figure}
%    \centering
     \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
     x unit = 1cm,  %<---------------------- New x unit 
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=0.7cm,
     vgrid, hgrid,
     title height=1,
%     title/.style={fill=none},
     title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar/.style={fill=blue},
     bar height=0.7,
%   progress label text={},
     group right shift=0,
     group top shift=0.7,
     group height=.3,
     group peaks width={0.2},
     inline]{1}{11}
    %labels

    \gantttitle[]{2017}{11} \\                 % title 
    \gantttitle{Jan}{1}                      % title 3
    \gantttitle{Feb}{1}
    \gantttitle{Mar}{1}
    \gantttitle{Apr}{1}
    \gantttitle{May}{1}
    \gantttitle{Jun}{1}
    \gantttitle{Jul}{1}
    \gantttitle{Aug}{1}
    \gantttitle{Sep}{1}
    \gantttitle{Oct}{1}
    \gantttitle{Nov}{1}\\

    % Setting group if any

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5}\\ 

    \ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4}\\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 2}{2}{10} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=2,inline=false]{Test 1}{6}{9} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 2}{7} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=5,inline=false]{Test 2}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 3}{10} \\       

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 3}{3}{8} \\ 

    \ganttbar[progress=90,inline=false]{Task A}{3}{5} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=50,inline=false, bar progress label node/.append style={below left= 10pt and 7pt}]{Task B}{3}{4} \\ \\
    \ganttbar[progress=30,inline=false]{Task C}{5}{6}\\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=70,inline=false]{Task D}{8}{10} \\ 

\end{ganttchart}
%    \caption{Gantt diagram for 2013--2014 Project}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi for helpful answer. Would appreciate if you suggest any changes to make the code more efficient. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 I think that if the result is what you want the efficiency doesn't matter unless you have to process hundreds Gantt diagrams. If efficiency means saving typing code, you could look at documentation and try to understand how `\gantttitlecalendar` works. This could save some lines in your code.